# Does PETA euthanize 95.9% of all animals under its care?

Tags: united-states, animal-welfare

The website [www.petakillsanimals.com/](https://www.petakillsanimals.com/) alleges on the home page (scroll down once) that "95.9% of animals under PETA's care have been killed in one year" as seen in this screenshot:

[image: 95.9% claim]

In that post, they make a sweeping claim that includes all of PETA. They claim that a staggering percentage of animals *in PETA's care* are killed. This claim is repeated with varying percentages throughout the website. For example, [here](http://www.petakillsanimals.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/PKA_Shareable.pdf) they claim the figure is "up to 97.4% in a given year", again referencing "the animals in its care" rather than "the animals in [specific shelter]":

[image]

However, when I click "[View the Evidence](https://www.petakillsanimals.com/proof-peta-kills/#petakills)" I essentially see the following:

- In one specific shelter, 85% of the animals admitted to the shelter were euthanized
- In three cases, PETA workers have wrongfully (and horribly) kidnapped and euthanized pets
- PETA uses tactics, campaigns, and ideology found disagreeable by the website.

The evidence presented regarding their Virginia headquarters [has been addressed in another, related question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/36808/does-peta-euthanize-unwanted-pets-at-its-virginia-headquarters). However, their claims regarding PETA as a whole have not been addressed.

**My question regards the "all animals in its care" portion of that statement**. On that website, they make broad sweeping claims about PETA's euthanasia rate, but then they only provide evidence for that statistic with one specific shelter. I see no evidence showing that this rate is representative of all of their shelters, nor that 95.9% or 97.4% of animals in their care are euthanized when looking at PETA as a whole. Indeed, I see no evidence presented about any other shelter besides the one in Virginia. However, they are not claiming that PETA euthanizes 95% of the animals in one shelter; they are claiming that PETA as a whole euthanizes 95% of all animals in their care. My question is about that claim.

**Are these claims made on their website substantiated by evidence of any kind? Does PETA as a national organization euthanize 95.9% of animals in their care?**

Comment: This question is offtopic as it is not about a notable claim but it does ask for further info to an existing question. This is best achieved by offering a bounty on that question. I linked the two questions as a convenience for all.

Comment: Appreciate the feedback. The claim is notable (they make it multiple times on their website), but that fact was not clearly shown in the question. I have updated to make that clear. Additionally, the linked question does not answer this question - that question addresses claims about one specific shelter. My question addresses claims about PETA as a whole. I have also updated to make that clear.